# Passing authentication from passport.js to puppeteer

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, passport.js, puppeteer

I have a web app that i have managed to authenticate it using passport.js OATH2 strategies.

When i launch puppeteer after i am authenticated, i am not authenticated - no session or cookie is passed from passport.js.

Can i pass authentication from passport.js to puppeteer?

Passport.js has the authorize function. MORE INFO HERE: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authorize/

Puppeteer has setCookie(). MORE INFO HERE: 
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetcookiecookies

I don't know if it's possible to add them together somehow...

Comment: The two of are completely different thing. In short: you use passport to add authentication on your site. You use puppeteer to authenticate on someone elses site.

Comment: I know it's just that for what i am building it makes sense.... It has to be possible.... If you consider that session hijacking attacks do this - illegally of course. There has to be a way to pass authentication data from one part of my application to another....

Comment: If simply serializing then copying the cookie from passport to setting it in puppeteer perhaps?

Comment: The selected answer contains useful data: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2087/how-to-hijack-a-session

Comment: Do you find out how to do this?

Comment: Nope... If you do, please post it here.